# Use jqgrid action formatter

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I fill grid by ashx file  and its work fine.
When i add action in grid ,data of cell shift to right and last column show Null.

Before add Action

[image]

After add Action

[image]

grid in firebug:

[image]

ashx:

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;
            string _search = request["_search"];
            string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
            string pageIndex = request["page"];
            string sortColumnName = request["sidx"];
            string sortOrderBy = request["sord"];
            int totalRecords;
  Collection<User> users = GetDummyUsers(numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy, out totalRecords);
            string output = BuildJQGridResults (users, Convert.ToInt32 (numberOfRows), Convert.ToInt32 (pageIndex), Convert.ToInt32 (totalRecords));
            response.Write (output);
        }
```

Create Users:

```
 private Collection<User> GetDummyUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords) {
            var data = new Collection<User> {
                new User(){ UserID = 1,UserName = "Bill Gates", FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Gates",EmailID = "test@microsoft.com",  },
                new User(){ UserID = 1,UserName = "Bill Gates", FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Gates",EmailID = "test@microsoft.com",  },
                new User(){ UserID = 1,UserName = "Bill Gates", FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Gates",EmailID = "test@microsoft.com",  },
            };
            totalRecords = data.Count;
            return data;
        }
```

ConvetTo json:

```
 private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection<User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords) {
            JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults ();
            List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow> ();
            foreach (User user in users) {
                JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow ();
                row.id = user.UserID;
                row.cell = new string[5];
                row.cell[0] = user.UserID.ToString ();
                row.cell[1] = user.UserName;
                row.cell[2] = user.FirstName;
                row.cell[3] = user.LastName;
                row.cell[4] = user.EmailID;
                rows.Add (row);
            }
            result.rows = rows.ToArray ();
            result.page = pageIndex;
            result.total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
            result.records = totalRecords;
            return new JavaScriptSerializer ().Serialize (result);
        }
```

grid:

```
     url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            autowidth: true,
            height: 100,
            colNames: ['ACTION', 'ID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'EmailID'],
            colModel: [
                         {
                             name: 'act', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                             formatoptions: {
                                 keys: true, 
                                 delOptions: true,
                                 delbutton:true,
                                 editbutton:false
                             }
                         },

                          { name: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true, },
                        { name: 'UserName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'FirstName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'LastName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'EmailID', width: 100, sortable: true },
            ],
            rowNum: 20,
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            recordpos: "left",
            ignoreCase: true,
            toppager: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            scrollOffset: 1,
        });
    });
```

Comment: I test grid by datatype: 'local' and create data in javascript its work!.But when grid fill by ashx(datatype: 'json') this problem comes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid is treating `actions` as real column and it expects data for it. The easiest way out of this is to add empty cell to your row on server side:

```
private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection<User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords) {
    JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults ();
    List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow> ();
    foreach (User user in users) {
        JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow ();
        row.id = user.UserID;
        row.cell = new string[6];
        row.cell[0] = String.Empty;
        row.cell[1] = user.UserID.ToString ();
        row.cell[2] = user.UserName;
        row.cell[3] = user.FirstName;
        row.cell[4] = user.LastName;
        row.cell[5] = user.EmailID;
        rows.Add (row);
    }
    result.rows = rows.ToArray ();
    result.page = pageIndex;
    result.total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
    result.records = totalRecords;
    return new JavaScriptSerializer ().Serialize (result);
}
```

As an alternative you can use jqGrid in `repeatItems: false` mode. First you need to change the jqGrid initialization script:

```
$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
    datatype: 'json',
    autowidth: true,
    height: 100,
    colNames: ['ACTION', 'ID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'EmailID'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'act', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true, delOptions: true, delbutton:true, editbutton:false } },
        { name: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true, },
        { name: 'UserName', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'FirstName', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'LastName', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'EmailID', width: 100, sortable: true },
    ],
    rowNum: 20,
    loadonce: true,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    recordpos: 'left',
    ignoreCase: true,
    toppager: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    scrollOffset: 1,
    jsonReader : { 
        repeatitems: false
    }
});
```

Now on server side you can no longer use array, you have to use object or dictionary. I will show the more generic approach which is dictionary. Assuming your solution is based on [this](http://codeasp.net/articles/using-jqgrid-with-asp-net/229/using-jqgrid-with-asp-net) sample, you will have to change `JQGridResult` class like this:

```
public class JQGridResults
{
    public int page;
    public int total;
    public int records;
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> rows;
}
```

Now your method can look like this:

```
private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection<User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords) {
    JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
    result.rows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    foreach (User user in users) {
        Dictionary<string, string> row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        row.Add("id", user.UserID.ToString());
        row.Add("UserID", user.UserID.ToString());
        row.Add("UserName", user.UserName);
        row.Add("FirstName", user.FirstName);
        row.Add("LastName", user.LastName);
        row.Add("EmailID", user.EmailID);
        result.rows.Add(row);
    }
    result.page = pageIndex;
    result.total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
    result.records = totalRecords;
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
}
```

This can be further optimized to avoid sending `UserId` twice, but this is not what is important from your question point of view.

Comment: I use [link](http://codeasp.net/articles/using-jqgrid-with-asp-net/229/using-jqgrid-with-asp-net) sampel.I add empty cell to row then work fine!but why this is happening?What is the fundamental solution?

Comment: @ZSH This is simply how jqGrid works. If the `repeatItems` option of `jsonReader` is set to `true` (which is default) the jqGrid is looking for columns values by indexes. In that case the `action` column is considered to have data and if it is not the last column it will take some other columns data. As an alternative you can use jqGrid with `repeatItems` set to `false`. This way jqGrid will be looking for data by name, but you have to use different serialization on server side as you no longer send back array but an object or dictionary.

Comment: @ZSH Also the sample you have linked shows only the basics. I believe you are using WebForms here, but in case you would be looking into ASP.NET MVC I strongly suggest to take a look here: https://tpeczek.codeplex.com/. You can found there sample project, strongly typed helper and links to articles describing jqGrid usage.

Comment: @tpeczekThank you very much.I understand now.But I use WebForms.Do you have an sample of use serialise insted of array in the WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

Code works completely fine in my browser. Try with this code. Hopw it works also just check in your webdeveloper tools are you getting any error there. 
Also paste your code for myDelOptions.

```
$("#datagrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            autowidth: true,
            height: 100,
            colNames: [ 'ACTION', 'EOSysNum', 'PctIndNum', 'PctLettSubject', 'PctAssignSubject', ],
            colModel: [
                         {
                             name: 'act', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                             formatoptions: {
                                 keys: true, 
                                 delOptions: true,
                                 delbutton:true,
                                 editbutton:false
                             }
                         },

                         { name: 'EOSysNum', index: 'UserID', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: false },
                         { name: 'PctIndNum', width: 140, sortable: true },
                         { name: 'PctLettSubject', width: 140, sortable: true },
                         { name: 'PctAssignSubject', width: 100, sortable: true },
                     ],
            rowNum: 20,
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            recordpos: "left",
            ignoreCase: true,
            toppager: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            scrollOffset: 1,
       });
```

Comment: I edit my question and add sampel. when action add in grid,Header column shift to right but cells in row not shift

Answer (score -1):

remove direction option from jqgrid and let us know it works or not